# To many "IF" statements

Tags: excel

Cell BF2=I55655612556ML11 I'm trying to make on long statement that will evaluate cells with varying codes in them to equal one of 29 possible answers. Some are easy and only take one IF statement, others, like this one, could have eight different outcomes. So far I have this =IF(LEFT($BF2,1)="I", IF(MID($BF2,8,2)="12", IF(MID($BF2,8,2)="15", IF(MID($BF2,8,2)="50","01 INPATIENT NON-MH"),""),""),""). I want a blank if it is incorrect, but in this case it is correct in the first two IF statements, but I'm getting a blank. I'll keep trying. I also have to over come the eighth possible outcome since there can only be 7 "IF" statements.

Comment: Typically you can convert your requirements into a table and then perform a lookup instead of nesting if statements.  Hard to recommend anything specific without knowing all of the logic and without any sample data and expected results.

Comment: Also, your nested ifs probably should be in the third argument, not in the second, because if `MID($BF2,8,2)="15"` is true, then, `MID($BF2,8,2)="50"`will always falls in the else (third part), which is blank.